# How do I toggle an image on click?

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, toggle

How do you toggle an image on click using jquery?

I'm trying to build upon an existing fiddle...but here's <del>[my updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/Insight_Web_Team/7Yveu/)</del> [my updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/Insight_Web_Team/7Yveu/15/).

-Edit- Thanks heaps for everyone's help but I left out that I still wanted the boxes to shift down when you click it to reveal the message. (I've updated the fiddle - link above - so that it's a lot simpler and less cluttered.) My problem is that the user won't know which box they've clicked on (because the numbers 1,2,3..won't be there to help them out.

The code so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
//rough multi slide. will shake elements below dropdowns
var prev = null;
function toggleDiv(e) {
  var divToToggle = $( $(this).find("a").attr('href') );
  if (prev && (!prev.is($(this)))) { //switch
    var prevDiv = $( prev.find("a").attr('href') );
    var divs = divToToggle.add(prevDiv); //add prevDiv into collection
    divs.slideToggle("slow"); //slideToggle all in collection
    prev = $(this);
  } else { //show/hide
    prev = divToToggle[0].style.display == 'block' ? null : $(this);
    divToToggle.slideToggle("slow");
  }
  return false;
//  e.preventDefault();
}

$('#document').ready(function() {
  $(".press").click(toggleDiv);
});
</script>
```

**What I would like -**
Once you click on an image, I would like for it to turn magenta (here's the source image btw for the magenta one: http://placehold.it/50x50/ff00ff).
....AND THEN once you click on ANOTHER box or click on it AGAIN, it has to revert back to the original image.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks heaps for any help...or at the very least, enjoy the fiddle.

I've already given this a try but it doesn't work..but this is exactly what I need:
http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/jquery-image-swap-using-click/

My fiddle based on [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/NPRfM/28/).

Comment: You need to embed the jQuery library in order for it to work.

Comment: Do you want the image to slide down or to fade to your 'after-click' image? This is do-able with just regular JQuery using Animations (or CSS3 animations) with some IF-ELSE statements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the update fiddle for your problem

http://jsfiddle.net/7Yveu/1/

```
//rough multi slide. will shake elements below dropdowns
var prev = null;
function toggleDiv(e) {
 var currentImg = $(e.currentTarget).find("img");
        $(".press img").attr("src", "http://placehold.it/140x140");
        currentImg.attr("src", "http://placehold.it/140x140/ff00ff");
}

$('#document').ready(function() {
  $(".press").click(toggleDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice and clean solution for you. You can change `$images` to any selector you want, and change the `image` variable to have any images you want :)

http://jsfiddle.net/EU6VW/1/

```
var $images = $('#SPIRIT').find('img'),
    image = { on: 'http://placehold.it/140x140/ff00ff', off: 'http://placehold.it/140x140' };

$images.on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', image.on === $(this).attr('src') ? image.off : image.on );
    $images.not(this).attr('src', image.off);
});
```

---

You could also slightly optimise this by changing it to the following code - this will only attach the event listener once (to `div#spirit`) instead of once per `img` tag.

```
var $container = $('#SPIRIT'),
    $images = $container.find('img'),
    image = { on: 'http://placehold.it/140x140/ff00ff', off: 'http://placehold.it/140x140' };

$container.on('click', 'img', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', image.on === $(this).attr('src') ? image.off : image.on );
    $images.not(this).attr('src', image.off);
});
```

---

If you then want to get silly in terms of optimisation, the `image.src` DOM property is supported in every major browser so you can remove a bit of jQuery overhead bloat;

```
var $container = $('#SPIRIT'),
    $images = $container.find('img'),
    image = { on: 'http://placehold.it/140x140/ff00ff', off: 'http://placehold.it/140x140' };

$container.on('click', 'img', function() {
    this.src = image.on === this.src ? image.off : image.on;
    $images.not(this).attr('src', image.off);
});
```